# Netbeans JAX-WS Client [ERROR] A class/interface with the same name

Tags: java, netbeans, jax-ws, ws-client

My WSDL URL is URLhttp://192.168.100.197:4443/PaymentServiceServerWS.asmx?wsdl. I want to generate java client in netbeans from the mentioned wsdl.
But it gives a class/interface with the same name is already in use,
use a class customization to resolve this conflict. I cant resolve this problem. 
But I could do it in cmd with the following comand:

```
wsimport http://192.168.100.197:4443/PaymentServiceServerWS.asmx?wsdl -s 
D:\PROJECTS\WS\my_path  -B-XautoNameResolution
```

After that I got all generated java code in netbeans, and trade code and got a Soap fault exception.

Just i want resolve this problem in netbeans and use customization xml file or other  files to generate it ,because netbeans was unable to genare it.
How can I generate this WDSL as java client without any issue?

Comment: I can't stand those errors and .Net Web Services are problematic about them O_o  you *might* be able to edit the wsiimport script itself and try adding the line ` -B-XautoNameResolution` and then netbeans would hopefully use it.

Comment: Yes i edited it, key=-B-XautoNameResolution and value=true  but error not sloved netbeans. In itellij idea same problem. "use a class customization to resolve this conflict".